# CNN,Bidirectional LSTM implementation with CTC loss in tensorflow for text recognition

Tags: python, lstm, bidirectional, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement the research paper idea https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.05717.pdf
using CNN, Bidirectional LSTM and CTC loss in order to predict text in images. I have found some resources on Github which includes code in tensorflow , however since I am new to Tensorflow it has been difficult for me to understand their code. Can someone please provide me with a very minimalist and simple code on how to implement the idea using some set of images and their corresponding labels like assets,finance etc. The labels are of varying lengths but the image size is fixed at width=200,height=20,depth=1.

This is text generation code:

```
data=[]
labels=[]
length=[]

def GenerateCharacters():  
    k = 1
    for filename in fonts:  
        font_resource_file = filename   
        for word in words:
            if len(word)>12:
                continue
            l=function(word)
            if l==-1:
              continue
            for font_size in font_sizes:
                font = ImageFont.truetype(font_resource_file, font_size)
                TEXT=word
                txt = TEXT
                (width, height) = font.getsize(txt)

                #New Image
                FOREGROUND = (255)
                background = Image.new('L', (width, height), color = 0)

                draw = ImageDraw.Draw(background)
                draw.text((0,0), txt, font = font, fill=FOREGROUND)

                w,h = background.size
                W = int(round(w/float(h)*22))
                req_im = np.asarray(background.resize((W, 22)))
                if(W<200):
                    req_im = np.hstack([req_im, np.zeros((22,200-W),dtype='uint8')])
                else:
                    req_im=Image.fromarray(req_im)
                    req_im=req_im.resize((200,22))
                    req_im=np.asarray(req_im)
                word_image=req_im
#                 outpath=out_dir+word
#                 if not os.path.exists(outpath):
#                     os.makedirs(outpath)
#                 file_name = os.path.join(outpath,str(k)+'.jpg')  
#                 cv2.imwrite(file_name,word_image)
                data.append(word_image)
                l=np.array(l)
                pad=np.full((1,12-l.shape[0]),-1)
                l=np.append(l,pad)
                labels.append(l)
                length.append(len(word))
                k = k + 1   
    return
```

Code for Model and Graph:

```
def run_ctc():
  graph = tf.Graph()
  with graph.as_default():
    input_data=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None, height, width, depth])
    labelss=tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.int32)
    sequence_length=tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])

    conv1=tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=input_data,
        filters=64,
        kernel_size=[3, 3],
        strides=[1,1],
        padding="same",
        activation=tf.nn.relu)
    print "Conv1",conv1.shape
    bn1=tf.layers.batch_normalization(inputs=conv1,axis=-1)
    print "BN1",bn1.shape
    pool1=tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=bn1,pool_size=[2,2],strides=[2,2])
    print "Pool1",pool1.shape
    conv2=tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=pool1,
        filters=128,
        kernel_size=[3, 3],
        strides=[1,1],
        padding="same",
        activation=tf.nn.relu)
    print "Conv2",conv2.shape
    bn2=tf.layers.batch_normalization(inputs=conv2,axis=-1)
    print "BN2",bn2.shape
    pool2=tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=bn2,pool_size=[2,2],strides=[2,2])
    print "Pool2",pool2.shape
    conv3=tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=pool2,
        filters=256,
        kernel_size=[3, 3],
        strides=[1,1],
        padding="same",
        activation=tf.nn.relu)
    print "Conv3",conv3.shape
    bn3=tf.layers.batch_normalization(inputs=conv3,axis=-1)
    print "BN3",bn3.shape
    pool3=tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=bn3,pool_size=[2,2],strides=[2,2])
    print "Pool3",pool3.shape
    conv4=tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=pool3,
        filters=512,
        kernel_size=[3, 3],
        strides=[1,1],
        padding="same",
        activation=tf.nn.relu)
    print "Conv4",conv4.shape
    bn4=tf.layers.batch_normalization(inputs=conv4,axis=-1)
    print "BN4",bn4.shape
    pool4=tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=bn4,pool_size=[2,2],strides=[2,2])
    print "Pool4",pool4.shape
    features = tf.squeeze(pool4, axis=1, name='features')
    print "CNN features",features.shape

    rnn_ = tf.transpose(features, perm=[1, 0, 2], name='time_major')
    print "RNN_seq",rnn_.shape



    weight_initializer = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.01)
    with tf.variable_scope('forward'):
        cell_fw = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(512,initializer=weight_initializer)
    with tf.variable_scope('backward'):
        cell_bw = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(512,initializer=weight_initializer) 
    with tf.variable_scope('Bdrnn',reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
      rnn_output,_ = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw, cell_bw, rnn_,
        sequence_length=sequence_length,
        time_major=True,
      dtype=tf.float32)

    rnn_output_stack = tf.concat(rnn_output,2,name='output_stack')
    logit_activation = tf.nn.relu
    weight_initializer = tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer()
    bias_initializer = tf.constant_initializer(value=0.0)
    logit_output = tf.layers.dense( rnn_output_stack, classes+1, 
                                        activation=logit_activation,
                                        kernel_initializer=weight_initializer,
                                        bias_initializer=bias_initializer)

    loss = tf.nn.ctc_loss(labelss,logit_output,sequence_length,time_major=True )
    total_loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)
    optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate=0.005, momentum=0.9).minimize(total_loss)      
    decoded, log_prob = tf.nn.ctc_greedy_decoder(logit_output, sequence_length)
    ler = tf.reduce_mean(tf.edit_distance(tf.cast(decoded[0], tf.int32),labelss))


    with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
      init=tf.global_variables_initializer()
      init_l=tf.local_variables_initializer()
      sess.run(init)
      sess.run(init_l)
      for i in range(epochs):
        train_cost = train_ler = 0
        print("Epoch: {}").format(i)
        for batch_no in range(total_train_batches):

          feed = {input_data: batch_data(train_data,batch_no,total_train_batches,batch_size),
                 labelss:sess.run(sparse_tuples(batch_data(train_labels,batch_no,total_train_batches,batch_size))),
                 sequence_length: batch_data(train_seq_len,batch_no,total_train_batches,batch_size)}

          da,l,seq=sess.run([input_data,labelss,sequence_length],feed_dict=feed)
#           print da.shape
#           print seq.shape

      #     prediction=tf.argmax(tf.nn.softmax(logit_output),axis=2)
          original=convert(train_labels[batch_no])
          print "Original Label",original
          batch_cost,_ = sess.run([total_loss,optimizer],feed_dict=feed)
          train_cost += batch_cost*batch_size
          train_ler += sess.run(ler, feed_dict=feed)*batch_size
          print "Batch_loss",batch_cost
          d = sess.run(decoded[0], feed_dict=feed)
          str_decoded = convert(d[1])
          print "Decoded Label",str_decoded
        train_cost /= num_train_examples
        train_ler /= num_train_examples

        for batch_no in range(total_val_batches):
          val_feed = {input_data: batch_data(val_data,batch_no,total_val_batches,batch_size),
                      labelss: sess.run(sparse_tuples(batch_data(val_labels,batch_no,total_val_batches,batch_size))),
                      sequence_length: batch_data(val_seq_length,batch_no,total_val_batches,batch_size)}

          val_cost,val_ler = sess.run([total_loss, ler], feed_dict=val_feed)

          log = "Epoch {}/{}, train_cost = {:.3f}, train_ler = {:.3f}, val_cost = {:.3f}, val_ler = {:.3f}"
          print(log.format(i+1, epochs, train_cost, train_ler,val_cost, val_ler))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  run_ctc()
```

The problem I am facing is that I get a batch loss of inf and decoded labels are not correct as compared to Original Label.

[Output I am getting(Image Link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXtBZ.png)

Comment: Welcome! That is a lot of sample code. But if this is minimal, and something  users of the platform can just drop in and use, that is probably OK. What problems are you having with the last code snippet? An error, or unexpected behavior?

Comment: It is giving me various errors. I dont actually know how to go about with running this part of the code in which we need to create a session, initialize the variables, calculate ctc loss and ultimately find accuracy for the model. I hope you get what I am trying to say! Thank you.

Comment: A simple text recognition system (similar to the CRNN model) implemented with TensorFlow and trained on the IAM dataset: https://towardsdatascience.com/2326a3487cd5

Comment: Thank you Harry!